# ubercart product submission form theming

Tags: theming, ubercart

how to render elements in the **mysite/node/add/product** form to make custom tpl in my ubercart product submission form. I tried node--add-product.tpl.php ; nothing is happening. Im a beginner to drupal. can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. TPL file should be page--node--add--product.tpl.php